# condition in conditionalPanel in shiny R not working well

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a dynamic app that depending on an input pops out other inputs or not. In the code below I want to pop out the checkboxInput with label x when the selectInput with label mdl is "First model". When I run the app and select the First model from the list the other checkboxInput does not appear. I know the condition has to be in javascript but I don't know that language. However I think that one of the conditions is right. Any suggestions? i have tried both codes shown below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "mdl", label = "Model", choices = list("First model",
      "Second model", "Third model"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.mdl == 'First model'",
        checkboxInput(inputId = "x", label = "Length")
      )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "mdl", label = "Model", choices = list("First model",
      "Second model", "Third model"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.mdl == First model",
        checkboxInput(inputId = "x", label = "Length")
      )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code.  The closing bracket (`)`) for your `selectInput` is misplaced in both examples, with the result that your `conditionalPanel` is "nested" within the `selectInput`.  Hence, disaster.

Comment: Thank you very much. I though conditionalPanel had to go inside the selectInput command... thank you again